# Matplotlib: Alter Every y-value

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to alter all y-values in the 2nd graph as such `**2/total` after list1 has been grouped by **axes.hist**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
figure1, axes1 = plt.subplots(nrows = 2, ncols = 1)
axes1[0].hist(x = list1, bins = np.arange(start = 0, stop = 6, step = 1), density = True)
axes1[1].hist(x = list1, bins = np.arange(start = 0, stop = 6, step = 1), density = True)
figure1.show()
```

[image]

How do I do that?

Resulting bin values for the 2nd graph should be:

```
0    0.217322
1    0.045818
2    0.038517
3    0.007593
4    0.000658
5    0.000115
```

Comment: What is `total`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not work with density. You want to calculate the histogram yourself using

```
h, bins = np.histogram(list, bins=np.arange(6))
```

Either normalise h as

```
h = h/np.sum(h)
```

or actually calculate the density

```
db = np.array(np.diff(bins), float) 
h = h/db/h.sum()
```

and manually plot the histograms either with some mpl hacks (put one count in each bin and parse the real number as weights

```
plt.hist(bins[:-1]+0.5, bins=bins, weights=h)
plt.hist(bins[:-1]+0.5, bins=bins, weights=h**2)
```

or use a dedicated package meant for plotting already calculated histograms (which mpl does not currently directly support)

```
import mplhep as hep
hep.histplot(h, bins, histtype='fill')
hep.histplot(h**2, bins, histtype='fill')
```